# Error al listar los datos.Column Index out of range, 7 > 6

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, attached-properties

Me hice un programa que extrae datos de mysql en una tabla pero al ejecutar me sale lo siguiente:

*Error al listar los datos.Column Index out of range, 7 > 6.*

Estuve revisando todo pero no encuentro donde está el error, alguno sabrá como orientarme???
A que se refiere ese índice fuera de rango? 7>6?

En las primeras 2 imágenes se puede observar el fragmento de código que me traería bien la información.
En la segunda 2 imágenes muestra el fragmento de código que debería traer mas datos pero no sale ni la tabla.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola Alejandro, puedes hacer el recorrido de bienvenida: https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour y lee como preguntar: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask para que tu pregunta sea bien recibida. El codigo no debe ir en imagenes sino en texto (para podes copiarlo) y con las herramientas de edicion de StackOverflow las formateas como codigo. En resumen: Agrega un ejemplo minimo, completo y verificable para que los demas puedar replicar tu error.

Comment: No nos castigues con código como imagen. Es imposible replicar tu situación desde una imagen. No te vamos a responder con imágenes :')